# RSpec fail in POST with error: failure/Error does not implement: call

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test a method `postMessage` endpoint from Slack API which is responsible to sending message on Slack.

As you see it's a simple HTTPost requests:

```
module Slack
  class Messenger
    def initialize(event)
      @event = event
    end

    def call
      HTTParty.post('https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage', body: params, headers: headers)
    end

    private

    attr_reader :event

    def params
      {
        token: Settings.slack_token,
        channel: Slack::GetUserId.new(parsed_email).call,
        text: Slack::ReporterTextMessage.new(parsed_name, parsed_ticket_number).call,
        as_user: true
      }
    end
#here are methods: parsed_email, parsed_name, parsed_ticket_number
```

So I've made RSpec test:

```
RSpec.describe Slack::Messenger do
  subject { described_class.new(event) }
  let(:event) { File.new('./spec/support/events/event.json').read }

  describe 'call' do
    let(:valid_params) do
      {
        token: 'token',
        channel: '12345',
        text: 'This is a message',
        as_user: true
      }
    end
    let(:response) { subject.call }
    before do
      allow(HTTParty).to receive(:post).and_return(valid_params)
    end

    it "returns specific params" do
      allow_any_instance_of(Slack::SlackMessenger).to receive(:call).and_return(valid_params)
      expect(response).to receive(:call).with(valid_params)
    end
  end
end
```

Somewhere my mock is sucks because I'm getting an error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to receive(:call).with(valid_params)
   {:token=>"token", :channel=>"12345", :text=>"This is a message", :as_user=>true} does not implement: call
```

EDIT:
after mocking I'm getting an error:

```
1) Slack::SlackMessenger call call HTTParty
   Failure/Error: subject.call

   TypeError:
     no implicit conversion of nil into String
   # /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/json-2.2.0/lib/json/common.rb:156:in `initialize'
   # /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/json-2.2.0/lib/json/common.rb:156:in `new'
   # /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/json-2.2.0/lib/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
   # ./source/parsers/jira_parser.rb:9:in `initialize'
   # ./source/slack/messenger.rb:30:in `new'
   # ./source/slack/messenger.rb:30:in `parsed_email'
   # ./source/slack/messenger.rb:23:in `params'
   # ./source/slack/messenger.rb:13:in `call'
   # ./spec/source/slack/messenger_spec.rb:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: It looks pretty unclear

Comment: What exactly you want to test? Which method/methods?

Comment: I want to test `call` method which is simple `HTTParty.post` request but as you see in `body:` I'm passing few things. Additional in params - `channel: ` and `text:` are calling two methods: `Slack::GetUserId.new(parsed_email).call` where I expect to received SlackId (e.g. '12345'); `Slack::ReporterTextMessage.new` is responsible for preparation of Slack message text so I expect to receive some message (e.g. `'This is a message'`). I suppose params hash could be mocked.

Comment: are you sure that `HTTParty` should return `valid_params` after receive `#post`?

Comment: If you need to check that `HTTParty` calling when you call your service than spec should look like in another way

Comment: @AlexGolubenko so how it should look like to check this `post` method?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look like:

```
RSpec.describe Slack::Messenger do
  subject { described_class.new(event) }
  let(:event) { File.new('./spec/support/events/event.json').read }

  describe 'call' do
    before do
      allow(HTTParty).to receive(:post).with(any_args)
    end

    it "call HTTParty" do
      subject.call
      expect(HTTParty).to have_received(:post)
    end
  end
end
```

But I recommend to stub these params:

```
def params
  {
    token: Settings.slack_token,
    channel: Slack::GetUserId.new(parsed_email).call,
    text: Slack::ReporterTextMessage.new(parsed_name, parsed_ticket_number).call,
    as_user: true
  }
end
```

To make it look like:

```
RSpec.describe Slack::Messenger do
  subject { described_class.new(event) }
  let(:event) { File.new('./spec/support/events/event.json').read }

  describe 'call' do
    let(:slack_url) { 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage' }
    let(:valid_params) do
      {
        token: 'token',
        channel: '12345',
        text: 'This is a message',
        as_user: true
      }
    end

    before do
      allow(Settings).to receive(:slack_token).and_return(valid_params[:token])
      ...
      allow(HTTParty).to receive(:post).with(slack_url, body: valid_params, header: ..)
    end

    it "call HTTParty with valid params" do
      subject.call
      expect(HTTParty).to have_received(:post).with(slack_url, body: valid_params, header: ..)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In both cases I'm getting   `1) Slack::Messenger call call HTTParty with valid params Failure/Error: subject no implicit conversion of nil into String`

Comment: Ok I think the problem is in `body: params` - for example how to mock `channel: Slack::GetUserId.new(parsed_email).call` ?

Comment: @mr_muscle `allow_any_instance_of(Slack::GetUserId).to receive(:call).and_return(..)` its short way but not the best

Comment: It's not working but the problem is in `params` mock because when I delete all params (except token) from teseted class I will be able to look what is inside of `params` (after adding pry before call of request). The problem is how to mock all other params